# List of string between other records loading error Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, load

I am stuck on a problem and really needed help.

Following is my data set

```
"counter","qid","i","qs","qt","tags","qvc","qac","aid","j","as","at"
"1",563355,62701,0,1235000081,"php,error,gd,image-processing",220,2,563372,67183,2,1235000501
"2",563356,15842,10,1235000140,"lisp,scheme,clojure",1047,16,563358,15842,3,1235000177
```

All the columns are separated by ',' and the sixth column is tags, which is a list of 2 to 5 tags also separated by ','.
I tried to create table with tags as a string and also as a array of string and both gives me first value from the list of tags (in this case `php` and `lisp`) and the remaining columns were null.

```
"1" 563355  62701   0   1235000081  "php    NULL    NULL    NULL    220 2   563372
"2" 563356  15842   10  1235000140  "lisp   NULL    NULL    NULL    1047    16  563358
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
"1" 563355  62701   0   1235000081  "php,error,gd,image-processing" 220 2   563372
"2" 563356  15842   10  1235000140  "lisp,scheme,clojure"   1047    16  563358
```

I did some research and found I can write a REGEXSERDE pattern to read the data and I am new to this and I do not know how to write regex pattern. Is there any other way beside regex. If not can someone help me write a regex pattern?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this will be change ',' delimiter with something else

Other approach will be to use [Open csv serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde/blob/master/readme.md) 
which will help you do this

Comment: changing the delimiter would not be an easy task since my table have close to half a million records.

Comment: use serde then for taking qouted data as input

Comment: use serde then for taking qouted data as input

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hive external table

```
create external table try3.tablename(
counter string,
qid int,
i int,
qs int,
qt int,
tags string,
qac int,
aid int )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'input.regex' = '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(\".*\"),(.*?),(.*?),.*'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/somelocation'
```